# Функция, которая считает проценты

Tags: python

Есть задача написать небольшую программу.

Сумма которую клиент должен оплатить - `1000` рублей, у клиента есть возможность перенести срок оплаты, стоимость продления срока - `14%` от остатка задолженности, клиент хочет оплатить `600` рублей из которых часть должна пойти в оплату суммы, оставшаяся часть пойдет в продление.

Формула такова:

```
1000 - 535(значение неизвестно) = 465 - это число пойдет в оплату суммы 
465 * 0.14 = 65,1 - стоимость продления
535 + 65.1 = 600
```

Как это возможно реализовать при помощи *Python*?

Comment: Ну покажите ваш код, и в чем сложности?

Answer (score 1):

Функция возвращает сумму продления

```
def procent(amount, procent,user_amount):
        #amount - общая сумма - 1000
        #procent - процентная ставка - 0,14
        #user_amount - плата пользователя - 600
        return (((float(user_amount)-float(amount))*float(procent))/(float(procent)-1))
```

Как использовать:

```
print(procent(1000, 0.14, 600))
```

Ответ:

```
65.11627906976746
```

Функция возврата 535, суммы которая пойдет на погашение:

```
def procent(amount, procent,user_amount):
    #amount - общая сумма 1000
    #procent - процентная ставка 0,14
    #user_amount - плата пользователя 600
    return float(amount)-((float(user_amount)-float(amount))/(float(procent)-1))
```

Вывод:

```
534.8837209302326
```

Функция определения остатка долга (465):

```
def procent(amount, procent,user_amount):
    #amount - общая сумма 1000
    #procent - процентная ставка 0,14
    #user_amount - плата пользователя 600
    return ((float(user_amount)-float(amount))/(float(procent)-1))
```

Вывод:

```
465.1162790697675
```

На будущее: на этом сайте вам просто так не помогут, должны быть уже какие-нибудь наработки

Comment: Я полный новичок, не могли бы вы объяснить как в первой функции возвращается процент? получается (600-1000)*0.14/0.14-1? 
 @danilshik

Comment: @Vladimir да, именно так.

Comment: Спасибо большое!